# jQuery ajaxOptions -error works, why doesn't Success?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery UI Tabs, and am using the sample code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. If this wouldn't be a demo.");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The issue here is I want to capture an AJAX success to grab a JSON object in inject the data into the DIV...

But this isn't working

```
$(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
                success: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                    alert('hello world');
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                    $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you copy & pasted, you're missing a comma after the success function before 'error'.

Comment: Sorry I have the comma, is still does nothing

Comment: Is it doing nothing when you add the success section, or still running the error?

Use FireBug to see what URL is being requested for the content and making sure that's correct - Or even if the ajax request is being made. Could help narrow down where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a comma before closing success function or is it a typo?

```
ajaxOptions: {
            success: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                alert('hello world');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. If this wouldn't be a demo.");
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Sorry, late answer

Answer (score 0):

Removed ajaxOptions and cache options; use beforeLoad event

(#7147) The ajaxOptions and cache options have been removed in favor of the beforeLoad event. See the 1.9 deprecation notice for full details.